# Removing everything between a tag (including the tag itself) using Regex / Eclipse

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to figuring out how Regex works, but this one is just frustrating.

I have a massive XML document with a lot of <`description>blahblahblah</description`> tags. I want to basically remove any and all instances of `<description></description>`.

I'm using Eclipse and have tried a few examples of Regex I've found online, but nothing works.

```
<description>(.*?)</description>
```

Shouldn't that work?

EDIT:

Here is the actual code.

```
<description><![CDATA[<center><table><tr><th colspan='2' align='center'><em>Attributes</em></th></tr><tr bgcolor="#E3E3F3"><th>ID</th><td>308</td></tr></table></center>]]></description>
```

Comment: Yes, that should work (although nested tags will mess it up). Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Thanks mmyers, I've edited the original post.

Comment: I actually meant the Java code, not the XML. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually not doing any Java. I just opened the XML file in Eclipse just so I could do a regex find/replace.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but I would expect its regex search facility to use Java's built-in regex flavor.  You probably just need to check a box labeled "DOTALL" or "single-line" or something similar, or you can add the corresponding inline modifier to the regex:

```
(?s)<description>(.*?)</description>
```

That will allow the `.` to match newlines, which it doesn't by default.

EDIT: This is assuming there *are* newlines within the `<description>` element, which is the only reason I can think of why your regex wouldn't work.  I'm also assuming you really are doing a regex search; is that automatic in Eclipse, or do you have to choose between regex and literal searching?